# HTML5 Video causing slow page scroll

Tags: html, flash, video, html5-video, flv

I'm working on a site where the client requested a video fill a div as the background. I have it in and working for myself but they keep complaining that they can't scroll. I have no issues on multiple computers scrolling. Is there some sort of common issue other than a slow machine that would cause this? Could it be a CSS issue? The staging site is here if it helps: http://arkroyal.staging.wpengine.com/

**UPDATE**

I am using a video hosting service and it seems this is only happening when the flash fallback is in there... I have set it to flash be default now and I can not scroll when my mouse is over it. So now I guess this is a flash issue?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user3285910's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789387/1272394), however, that's not to say there isn't anything you can do about it.

When I first went I didn't not attempt to scroll, I just let the entire page load. Afterwards I checked the load times for the media, the Winsta MP4 took 27.36 seconds to load. That's in Chrome on a T1 line. I used Chrome because the webkit browsers are known for their *laggy* video lading.

With that information I would look at changing the preload value for the `<video>`. Currently it's `"none"`. There are a lot of different approaches to preloading data and you cannot account for everyone's PC speed, bandwidth, etc.

I would recommend letting the browser determine their capabilities for you and adjusting accordingly. Usually 5-7 seconds of preload is enough to get around the *jumping* behavior. [Here](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/) is a link to an article that goes into more detail with analysis.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the staging site, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the site itself, but more the video you are using.  The video is high quality and will cause systems to slow down drastically.  If this is the video they want as the BG, I would see if you couldn't get the video resolution lowered drastically, as this will cause issues in the rendering on some systems.  This will also make users unable to scroll down the page, because their video card is busy trying to render the images that are being produced by the BG video.